# jersey archetype sun or glassfish

Tags: maven, jersey, repository

I´m new with Jersey and I have problems with the installation. Specially with the error:

> Can't resolve Archetype
>   org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-heroku-webapp:2.26

I already looked for solutions:

- adding a remote catalog
- adding a new Maven Archetype locally
- proxy setting are working (I can access a web page using my internal browser)

Now, I noticed that when creating a new Maven project and selecting the archetype it appears:

> com.sun.jersey.archetypes

Can I use that to run jersey? or Is only with

> org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `com.sun.jersey.archetypes` <- Jersey 1.x ([see docs](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/1.19.1/index.html))
- `org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes` <- Jersey 2.x ([see docs](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html))

For new projects, use 2.x