# Setting up maven folder m2 on windows 10

Tags: eclipse, maven, jersey

I just installed eclipse oxygen and I want to program using maven. I´m newbie with maven and I wonder if I need to set up something else, related with the m2 folder.

I would like to install Jersey, but I got the error :

> Can't resolve Archetype
>   org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-heroku-webapp:2.21
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact

I already tried different options, this was my previous post [jersey post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176372/jersey-archetype-sun-or-glassfish)

I´m looking for other alternatives, and in other posts I read about the folder m2, do I need to do something in there? if so, could you please provide a link with the steps.

Thank you!

Comment: are you behind any proxy?

Comment: yes, but when I installed a new software, I was able to connect to the repository  http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Comment: A proxy can show a lot of different behaviours - it can block access depending on the http address, the calling program, the user, the phase of the moon,...

Comment: Now I got problems in connecting. The proxy setting should be in HTTP , Direct, Manual or Native?

Comment: You need to ask your system administrator what you need to get through the proxy. You can add proxy settings to your settings.xml

Comment: You can check the proxy seeings in settings.xml file...<proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.somewhere.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>

Comment: I don´t have that file, but I´m creating it, it should only contain those lines?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html                                   like this, from line 4 to 15?

Comment: I added the file but still is not able to connect to the repository

Comment: You need to mention the correct proxy details in that file.

Answer (score 0):

The artifact `org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-heroku-webapp:2.21` is in MavenCentral. If you cannot get it you either:

- use a `settings.xml` which does not allow you do access MavenCentral (by e.g. mirroring it). If you never wrote or copied a `settings.xml` this will not be the case.
- or you have network problems. Your proxy or firewall might restrict the access to MavenCentral. This is especially likely if you are in a company network.

Comment: Yes, i´m trying to make it work, but do I need to add/set up something with the m2 folder?

Comment: The .m2 folder contains your settings.xml (if you have any). This can be used to configure proxy settings. The settings.xml is the only relevant file for you in this folder.